# How to access files in Laravel storage from a third part application (a Java app for instance) with some basic password protection/authentication?

Tags: java, laravel, api, authentication

I have been working with Laravel for a little less than a month; so, not aware of all the pre-defined functionality it has to offer. I have a bunch of CSV files in my Laravel application storage and I want to access them from another application (a Java application that processes those CSV files to produce some results).

What would be the best way to go about it?

I have a basic user management system set up and the users fill in an application form (which is where the csv files come from). These files are stored in the Laravel storage.

My current approach without using any built-in authentication (because I am not confident about how to use it in this case) is to have a controller return a downloadable file on a POST request (the file just gets downloaded upon request). The data sent with the POST request is the filename and a password, which if correct, returns the file; otherwise, gives an error. Is this a good way to approach the problem?

I simply want to retrieve the files by making a request from the Java application. Also, some basic protection is required so that everyone cannot access the files by making such requests. Any help or resources would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use digitalocean space as additional shared storage between two servers (php and java) then make storage access private using digitalocean dashboard and finally add new website cors on space settings has your java domain and its http verbs (get post delete...). With this configuration you could access your cloud storage between two servers safely using access key and secret key.